# How to disable .onDelete- or how to use .deleteDisabled on a per row basis in a list?

Tags: ios, arrays, swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm trying to disable deleting of rows in a list, on a per row basis, based on a Bool from a core data item. The goal is to only allow list items that have been marked as paid, to be deleted. While I'm able to make my delete function only delete "paid" items, the user will still be able to slide to delete visually, and I want to remove that.

I have a list, with a forEach from Core Data.
I use .onDelete with a delete-function, that works fine.
I'm trying to use .deleteDisabled, but I'm not able to get it to use a bool from Core Data. I'm only able to get it to enable or disable deletion for all of the rows at the same time.

Any way of doing this, hopefully without UIkit?

Comment: onDelete can not be dynamically placed on the element. You might have to check it inside your delete action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

my 2 cents for Xcode 12:

```
....

 List () {
      ForEach(self.items) { item in 
           let disabled = item.protected // ANY attribute of struct item
           MyFileCell(file: file) // ANY swift elements.. Text()....
           .deleteDisabled(disabled)
       }
       .onDelete(perform: delete)
  } // end of list
```

...